unable to ping my router from outside
I have a TPLink Archer C2 AC750. My friend was able to ping me half a year ago, but the problem appeared after resetting the router. Now I'm getting "Request timed out." after calling "ping [IP]" in win cmd. I need an opportunity to ping my router from the outside. I don't know anything about networking stuff so I'm kinda confused.
with tracert command:
Tracing route to xxx-xxx-xx-x.broadband.kyivstar.net [xxx.xxx.xx.x]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1 1 ms 1 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1

2 5 ms 4 ms 5 ms 46-xxx-x-xxx.broadband.kyivstar.net [46.xxx.x.xxx]

3 * * 1 ms 172.xx.x.xxx

4 * * * Request timed out.

5 10 ms 11 ms 12 ms xxx-xxx-xx-x.broadband.kyivstar.net [xxx.xxx.xx.x]

I also have digged in router web interface quite a bit:
Connection type: Dynamical IP IP address: 100.79.x.xx Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0 Gateway: 100.79.xxx.xxx

I unchecked the "Ignore Ping packets from WAN port" flag, but after that I am only able to ping my public IP (that's shown on whatismyip website etc.) and IP adress that starts with 100.xx from PC in this network, not from the outside.

Try calling and asking for a dynamic public IP (it's free). It worked for me in the past with this ISP. There is also an option to pay for static IP.

Your IP-address starts with 100.79.
That indicates your ISP uses Carrier Grade NAT and is NOT supplying you with a public ip-address.
Many ISP's do this, because ip-addresses are getting scarce and CGNAT allows them to serve a large group of customers using a much smaller pool of ip-addresses. (Without CGNAT they would need 1 ip-address for each customer.)
Because the ip-address is not public you can, in general, NOT ping it from any other ip-address on the internet.
(Only if the connection you are trying to ping from is also on the same ISP and in the same CG-NAT pool it can work. And even then it is not guaranteed to work. There could be other hurdles thrown up by the ISP as well. Although in your case it does work.)
There is nothing you can do about this from your end. This is totally controlled by the ISP.
